# Equivalent of Dragon NaturallySpeaking's HeardWord function in Dragon Dictate 4

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

In Dragon NaturallySpeaking's Advanced Scripting Command on Windows, [HeardWord](http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6141/~/using-the-heardword-function-in-advanced-scripting-commands) is a function that enables Dragon NaturallySpeaking to behave as if the specified word, word sequence, or voice command was received by the recognizer. HeardWord can be used to create a command that executes a series of other commands, or that has the same function as an existing command but a different name.

Here is an example to type a closing remark, in bold type, at the end of a document.

```
HeardWord "go", "to", "bottom"
HeardWord "set", "font", "bold"
Wait 1
SendDragonKeys "{Enter 2}" + "This document was dictated using Dragon NaturallySpeaking."
```

In [Dragon Dictate 4](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/dragon-dictate/index.htm), is there any way to write a voice command that calls other voice commands (e.g. a voice command that would call the built-in command "Cap")?

Since I bought the product more than six month ago I do not have access to the customer support anymore. Searching on Google didn't bring any interesting results.

Answer (score 1):

It can depends in which application you dictate.

The online help is accessible by clicking on the Dragon icon in the menu bar.

Or click here: http://www.nuance.com/products/help/dragon/dragon-for-mac/enx/Content/GetStarted.htm

Else, there is the Commands manager in the same menu in the menu bar.

On Mac, you can use Applescript with Dragon Command manager.

Comment: What is the equivalent of Dragon NaturallySpeaking's HeardWord function in Dragon Dictate?

Comment: :( You put a -1 for my answer. That is not fair. I am new to StackExchange in the sense that I find it difficult to earn some points on the site to allow me to go a little bit further. If I didn't posted an answer I could not even put a comment to ask complementary questions. Anyway, I tell you, I wrote to Nuance and asked for you "Is there an equivalent to the Windows Dragon NaturallySpeaking's "Heardword" function in Dragon Dictate 5.0.4 for Mac? If yes, would you mind telling me where I can find it ?" Sorry for my English. Wait and see… if you will. I'll be back.

Comment: I didn't downvote! somebody else did. Thanks, please let me know what Nuance replied, I'm curious.

Comment: Oops, sorry :s Anyway, Nuance gave me a reply… with a question. Stay tuned. I have had a look at the Command manager in the Dragon Dictate 5.0.4 I own. It seems only possible to stack some keyboard shortcuts and to trigger them with one voice command. Else, I bet there will only be an Apple Script or Automator to compose more complex scenarios.

Comment: I have received the final reply. The answer is No :( I have been told that anyhow this functionality on Windows is only for Pro or Medical versions.   The support will forward the request to the dev team.

Comment: Feel free to vote for my answer then  :) what would you like to do with macro commands? No doubt you will get some help from the present community.